# Challenges in Angular Component Routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have defined a child component routing.

1. I am not able navigate to the default routing from the routerLink.
2. Parent path has ':id', so for children routing it's working with a prefix ':id' only.

Route

```
{
    path: ':id', component: InterviewComponent,
    children: [                          
      {
        path: '',
        component: InterviewQuestionsComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':id/interview',
        component: InterviewGridComponent
      }
    ]

  }
```

Anchor tags

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li>
        <a routerLink=""><i class='interviewQuestions'></i>&nbsp; <span style="cursor: pointer;">Interview Questions</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink=":id/interview"><i class='interviews'></i>&nbsp; <span style="cursor: pointer;">Interviews</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

1. I am not able to navigate to default router with 'routerLink=""'
2. Routes working only with "path: ':id/interview'"

Comment: share a stackblitz that is strange

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that I observed here,

1. if I understand you correctly what you are trying to do is,

   **/1** should render **InterviewQuestionsComponent**

   **/1/interview** should render **InterviewGridComponent**

right? correct me if I am wrong.

if this is what you want then modify your routes with below,

```
{
path: ':id', component: InterviewComponent,
children: [                          
  {
    path: '',
    component: InterviewQuestionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'interview',
    component: InterviewGridComponent
  }
]
}
```

2. To navigate to each of these components, you will need 'id', which is a path param, so what you have done in routerLink is not correct.

modify it like below,

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
  <li>
    <a routerLink="1"><i class='interviewQuestions'></i>&nbsp; <span style="cursor: pointer;">Interview Questions</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a routerLink="1/interview"><i class='interviews'></i>&nbsp; <span style="cursor: pointer;">Interviews</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here I have hardcoded '1' in the path, you can make it dynamic using Angular bindings. 
Here's a working example on stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wipkyq

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

With "1/Interview" the URL coming out is "#/Interview/1/1/interview" with extra ID param.
same with routerLink="1" -> "#/Interview/1/1"

Comment: Did you see stackblits that I made? it is working fine in that?